# how to parse and fetch Map<String, List> flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, parsing, fetch

how to translate this answer into my project using a giving basis.

this is the response

```
mySelectedEvents = {
      "2022-09-13": [
        {"eventDescp": "11", "eventTitle": "111"},
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-30": [
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-20": [
        {"eventTitle": "ss", "eventDescp": "ss"}
      ]
    };
```

How to parse and fetch this array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over each item and access it:

```
for(var event in mySelectedEvents)
{
   for(var eventInfo in event)
   {
      print(eventInfo["eventDescp"]);
      print(eventInfo["eventTitle"]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i make my bdd . i don't nw how to make the model and make a void function to parse and fetch.

```
CREATE TABLE `event_date` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Déchargement des données de la table `event_date`
--

INSERT INTO `event_date` (`id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, '2022-09-13'),
(2, '2022-09-30'),
(3, '2022-09-20');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `event_list`
--

CREATE TABLE `event_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `descript` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `id_event_date` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Déchargement des données de la table `event_list`
--

INSERT INTO `event_list` (`id`, `descript`, `title`, `id_event_date`) VALUES
(1, '11', '111', 1),
(2, '22', '22', 1),
(3, '22', '22', 2),
(4, 'ss', 'ss', 3);
```